# Increment operator with array name, what does it do?

Tags: c++, arrays, increment

I'm basically using this code to get my head around the movement of values with arrays. I'm fine up to where it says `++mode[i][0]` near the bottom. What does this actually increment? This is not my code by the way.

```
    int main()
    {
        int arr[10];
        int mode[10][2];

        cout << "Enter 10 integer values\n";
        for (int l = 0; l < 10; l++)        
        {                                   
            cout << "value " << l << ":";   
            cin >> arr[l];  
        }


        int i, j, temp;

        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (j = 9; j > i; j--)
            {
                if (arr[j] < arr[j - 1])
                {
                    int temp = arr[j];      
                    arr[j] = arr[j - 1];    
                    arr[j - 1] = temp;

                    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
                    {
                        cout << arr[x] << " ";
                }
                cout << "\n";
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Highest number = " << arr[9] << "\nLowest number = " << arr[0];

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            mode[j][i] = 0;
        }

    }
    mode[0][0] = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j + 1])
            {
                ++mode[i][0];
                mode[i][1] = arr[i];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `++mode[i][0]` is `++(mode[i][0])`. The `++` here is not used "with array name", as you seem to believe. It is applied to an array *element* of type `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see it that way :

```
++(mode[i][0]);
```

So it will increment the value stored in `mode[i][0]`

Answer (score 0):

since `mode[i][0] = some_int`, specifically the first element in the array at index `[i]` it’s incrementing the value stored there

Answer (score 0):

`operator[]` has a [higher precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `operator++`, so `++mode[i][0]` is actually treated as `++(mode[i][0])`, not `(++mode)[i][0]` like you are thinking.

The code is incrementing a specific `int` in the array, it is not incrementing the array itself.